# How do I delete folders & files without returning errors for non-existent/missing folders

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

What is an appropriate Windows command to delete a directory and its contents, whether or not they exist? In other words, if the folder exists, delete it and all its contents, and if it doesn't exist, do nothing and don't complain about it.

(Context: build script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a script where you first check if exists:

```
IF exist "directory_path" (del /s /f /q "directory_path")
```

If you still get output, drop a `@echo off` before that command.

Or simply:

```
del /s /f /q "directory_path"
```

If it doesn't exist it will do nothing.

- `f` from force
- `s` from subdirectories (recursive)
- `q` from quiet